# Cutting convex polygons into affine-equivalent quadrilaterals

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, affine-geometry

We continue from [Tiling the plane with quadrilaterals that are mutually non-congruent and affine equivalent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447385/tiling-the-plane-with-quadrilaterals-that-are-mutually-non-congruent-and-affine)

**Question:** Can any convex polygon $C$ be partitioned into some finite number $m$ of quadrilaterals that are mutually affine-equivalent? If the answer is "yes", how does one do it for a given $n$-gon efficiently, minimizing $m$?

**Note:** It *appears* that a general triangle cannot be cut into any finite number of trapezoids. So, if $C$ is a triangle, the required partition, if it exists, *might* have to be into non-trapezoid quadrilaterals.

[Tiling the plane with pair-wise non-congruent and mutually similar triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445805/tiling-the-plane-with-pair-wise-non-congruent-and-mutually-similar-triangles) might be related.